# Instead of apk format file without any extension is created while publishing an android app

Tags: android, apk

[image]I am new to publishing android app to google play store. When i am trying to publish app using signed release key and follow all the steps in the previously posted questions, my app is created, but without any extension.

Please guide me in this issue.

Below was an image of that file created format in the output.(problem is created file was not in apk format). I dont know where i missed.

[image]

Comment: Any chance your system is set to hide file extensions?

Comment: @ChrisStratton i created release key for my another project. It was working fine.

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on it and checking properties to determine file type?

Comment: @MikeDocherty ya it was showing as Type:File.

Comment: When you're in the final export window, does it have the extension .apk showing?

Comment: Try adding it in. Whenever I export mine it always says: applicationname.apk

Comment: @AdamShort you are correct. I tried with extension format. Now i got an apk file. Thanks for your answer. Before release i dint found anything like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried same steps for an other app which work perfectly and generated an apk file. But unfortunately this apk was generated only after giving the extension propely.